# Select many where on join table

Tags: mysql

There are 2 primary tables:

**products**

- id
- name

**filters**

- id
- name

And one connection table

**product_filter**

- product_id
- filter_id

Say we have several products and several filters. And we have one special product with id 1 which is connected with two filters. The names of these filters are black and white with ids 1 and 2. So in connection we have two fields: (product_id: 1, filter_id: 2), (product_id: 1, filter_id: 2). I want to select that product.

What I have tried. First I tried use `where or` clauses: `select * from products join product_filter on product_filter.product_id = products.id join filters on filters.id = product_filter.filter_id where filters.name = "black" or filters.name = "white"`. But this select products which have only black or only white filter as well. Usage `and` clauses instead of `or` does not select anything at all.

Comment: The usual solution involves an IN(), a GROUP BY, a HAVING, and a COUNT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can  JOIN `filters` table twice in this case like

```
select * from products 
join product_filter on product_filter.product_id = products.id 
join filters on filters.id = product_filter.filter_id 
join filters fl on fl.id = product_filter.filter_id 
where filters.name = 'black' 
and fl.name = 'white';
```